# Trigger hotstring ONLY when preceded by alphanumberic characters

Tags: autohotkey

I know about using `?` in a hotstring (e.g. `:?:btw::by the way`) to allow the hotstring to fire after an alphanumberic character. However, is there a way to make it fire **only** when preceded by an alphanumberic character? For example, so it doesn't trigger on `#btw` or `@btw` or `:btw` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of is to make a `hotstring` for every alphanumeric character.

```
:?:abtw::by the way
:?:bbtw::by the way
:?:cbtw::by the way
.
.
.
:?:Ybtw::by the way
:?:Zbtw::by the way
:?:1btw::by the way
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

The library [RegEx Powered Dynamic Hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15015-regex-powered-dynamic-hotstrings/) can do this for you. Save the above library in the same directory as your script and run the following:

```
#Include DynamicHotstrings.ahk

hotstrings("[\w]btw", "btw") ; [\w] is the regular expression for a single character word
Return

btw:
    SendInput, by the way
Return
```

Comment: This appears to be the updated version: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/114764-regex-dynamic-hotstrings/#entry667522