# text replacement ONLY if hotstring is typed at beginning of a line

Tags: autohotkey

Here's what I tried.

```
:*:func::
{
   clipboard = startOfLine
   Send +{LEFT}^c
   clipwait
   if(clipboard == "startOfLine")
       send,function xxx() {{}`n`n`n{}}{UP 2}{BACK}{TAB}
}
return
```

but the clipboard never gets replaced

is there a better trick to determine if you are at the beginning of a line?

P.S. This is for typing in an IDE

Comment: this might have an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287501/trigger-hotstring-only-when-preceded-by-alphanumberic-characters?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Send {Home}+{End}^c ;copies current line
If Clipboard =  ;  checks to see if clipboard is empty
    send,function xxx() {{}`n`n`n{}}{UP 2}{BACK}{TAB}
```

Comment: didn't see this answer till now - abandoning this technique, but at least I learned a technique to copy the current line. Thanks!